# how do I add curl(libcurl) to my C project in CLION?

Tags: c, unix, curl, libcurl, clion

I have to make a Linux application that will open websites from a queue and download them and store them as a file on my PC while using threads. 
We got a web_request.c and web_request.h class that uses OPENSSL and CURL for the job, we may use the functions from web_request.c to download the sites we got lined up on our queue.
I have been trying to compile after curl with no success so far and definitely could use some help.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(BS06 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -lm -lssl -lcrypto -pthread -lcurl)

add_executable(BS06 main.c)
```

How I include web_request.h on main.c to use their functions:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <values.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "include/web_request.h"
```

How i include curl in web_Request.c

```
#include "web_request.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <openssl/opensslv.h> // OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strncmp
```

CURL --version:

```
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
```

curl-config --libs:

`-lcurl`

Error:

```
 [50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/main.c.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/bin/sh: 1: -lssl: not found
/bin/sh: 1: -lcrypto: not found
/bin/sh: 1: -pthread: not found
/bin/sh: 1: -lcurl: not found
CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/main.c.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/main.c.o] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/BS06.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'BS06' failed
make: *** [BS06] Error 2
```

Comment: Possibly related? >> (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to to link curl library with executable. Does it help if you rewrite your CMakeList.txt like:

```
project(BS06 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED) 

include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(BS06 main.c)
target_link_libraries(BS06 ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```